# Accessing variables in Automator

Tags: automator

I am following an [Automator tutorial](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automation/automator-101-building-your-first-workflow/) and I can't figure out how to access variables like 'Current year' or 'Current user' in my workflow.

Suppose I am wanting to `Add Photos to Album`. How could I add them to a new album containing the current year in the name? (e.g. "Photos from ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the top bar, activate left "Variables". Then drag the required variable to the workflow area.

This will insert an action "Query variable".

Enable "Show results", and do a single step to execute this action.

The result of this action can then be forwarded to any next action.

[image]